# Find what physical interface is external facing

Tags: networking, interface

I would like to know how I can bash script a check to see which interface has an external connection (eth0, eth1, wlan0, em1 and em2) so i can get a script to work on any machine without having to hardcode the interface in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ip route show` and extract the interface name(s) of interest. For example, to extract the name of the interface which has direct access to the default gateway:

```
$ ip route show | sed -e 's/^default via [0-9.]* dev \(\w\+\).*/\1/'
ens192
```

For IPv6 use `ip -6 route show`.

The original question asks for *the interface which has an external connection*, which is more general than the interface which has direct access to the default gateway. I cannot test this, but probably looking for `0.0.0.0/0` in the output if of `ip route show` would help.